# Use fill_value outside boundaries with scipy.interpolate.griddata and method=nearest

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, qhull

Function [`scipy.interpolate.griddata`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html) allows to specify the keyword `fill_value`, for which the doc states:

> Value used to fill in for requested points outside of the convex hull of
>   the input points. If not provided, then the default is nan. 
>   **This option has no effect for the ‘nearest’ method.**

However, I need to specify a `fill_value` to use outside of the boundaries when
using `method='nearest'` with 2D data. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 6):

This can be relatively easily achieved with the following work-around:

1. run with `method='nearest'`
2. run again with `method='linear'`; here the outside region is filled with `np.nan`.
3. wherever there is a NaN in the result of 2. assign your desired `fill_value` to the result of 1.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

def func(x, y):
    return x*(1-x)*np.cos(4*np.pi*x) * np.sin(4*np.pi*y**2)**2

grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[0:1:100j, 0:1:200j]

points = np.random.rand(100, 2)
values = func(points[:,0], points[:,1])

grid_z0 = griddata(points, values, (grid_x, grid_y), method='nearest')
grid_z1 = griddata(points, values, (grid_x, grid_y), method='linear')

fill_value = 123  # Whatever you like
grid_z0[np.isnan(grid_z1)] = fill_value
```

A less ad-hoc approach would be to compute the convex hull explicitly and use it to assign the fill value. This would require more effort but might run faster.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's indeed an easy solution! Although in practice, it'd use over twice the time required with a single `method='nearest'`. I’ll have a look at [`scipy.spatial.ConvexHull`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html), it might do the trick.

Comment: @Arcturus B, did you come up with a better solution for your problem by using ConvexHull? You could post it and accept it.